# Column does not exist AWS Timestream Query error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am trying to apply WHERE clause on DIMENSION of the AWS Timestream records. However, I got the error: `Column does not exist`

Here is my table schema:
[The table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gyMi.png)
[The table measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA0t7.png)

First, I will show all the sample data I put in the table

```
SELECT username, time, manual_usage
FROM "meter-reading"."meter-metrics"
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 4
```

The result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7TVI.png)

What I wanted to do is to query and filter the records by the Dimension ("username" specifically).

```
SELECT * 
FROM "meter-reading"."meter-metrics" 
WHERE measure_name = "OnceADay"
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```

Then I got the Error: `Column 'OnceADay' does not exist`

I tried to search for any quotas for Dimensions name and check for error in my schema:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/ts-limits.html#limits.naming
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/ts-limits.html#limits.system_identifier

But I didn't find that my "username" for the dimension violate any of the above rules.
I checked for some other queries by AWS Blog, the author used the WHERE clause for the Dimension filter normally:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/effective-queries-for-common-query-patterns-in-amazon-timestream/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after I tried with the sample code. Turn out it was a silly mistake I believe.

Using apostrophe **(')** instead of single quotation marks **("")** solved my problem.

```
SELECT * 
FROM "meter-reading"."meter-metrics" 
WHERE username = 'OnceADay'
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```